# Hide a div on startup

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div with an id="test" on loading the page and then when you click, the div will appear. This is what I have so far for my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I have for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $("#Test").hide().load("Test.html", function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
});
});
```

It is still not working though, if someone could please help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is case-sensitvie. You should use `$("#test")` not `$("#Test")`. You can also hide the paragraph with pure CSS with `#test {display:none}`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Xw53A/)** (jQuery)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6yNzb/)** (CSS)

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#test{display:none;)
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#test").click(function(){
      $(this).toggle('slow',1);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define:

```
<p id="test">Test</p>
```

But in the Javascript you use:

```
$("#Test").hide().load("Test.html", function(){
```

Javascript is case sensitive and using:

```
$("#test").hide().load("Test.html", function(){
```

Should fix the problem